# PHP use mySQL to check existing username

Tags: php, mysql

I have been following this tutorial for building a simple registration / login script.

http://forum.codecall.net/topic/69771-creating-a-simple-yet-secured-loginregistration-with-php5/

I am new with PHP, but I have a lot of experience using C++, so I thought the transitions wouldn't be too hard, I just need to figure out the syntax. I also did a very very quick introduction to mySQL at university, so I thought it would be a lot easier to use mySQL to check for an existing username when the user has registered, though my knowledge isn't too good. I thought something like this would work;

```
SELECT username
FROM codecalltut
WHERE username = username;
```

Would this actually work? It is selecting the username from the database codecalltut and then it checks to see if the username being inputted is already a username? Even if this is correct I don't know how to include it in my PHP.

I've tried using

```
$qry = "SELECT username
    FROM codecalltut
    WHERE username = username;"
```

But I just get a syntax error when it moves to the next statement.

```
<?php 
    $qry = "SELECT username
        FROM codecalltut
        WHERE username = username;"

//if register button was clicked.
} else {
$usr = new Users; //create new instance of the class Users
$usr->storeFormValues( $_POST ); //store form values

//if the entered password is match with the confirm password then register him
if( $_POST['password'] == $_POST['conpassword'] ) {
echo $usr->register($_POST); 
} else {
//if not then say that he must enter the same password to the confirm box.
echo "Password and Confirm password not match"; 
}
}

?>
```

This is the query used to construct the database:

```
CREATE DATABASE `codecalltut` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `codecalltut`;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varbinary(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`,`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

This is the HTML code for when the user clicks "Register"

```
<li class="buttons">
                         <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
                            <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="location.href='index.php'" />
                     </li>
```

Comment: where is the code that executes the query? in the example it looks like `username = :username`. `:username` is a placeholder. `username = username` makes no sense.

Comment: There's a missing `;` _after_ the assignment to `$qry`.  The `;` inside the SQL is probably harmless.

Comment: the username is the table inside my database. I thought $qry executed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML form for Registration

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='username' />
    <input type='password' name='password' />
    <input type='password' name='re-password' />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>
```

---

Your PHP code

```
if($_POST){

        if(empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password']) && empty($_POST['re-password'])) {
            echo 'Please enter all fields';
        }else {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $re_password = $_POST['re-password'];

        if($password !== $re_password){
            echo 'Both passwords do not match';
        }else {

            $db_name = 
            $db_user = 
            $db_pass = 

            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 
                array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true )
        );

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
            $stmt->execute(array($username, $password));

            if($stmt->rowCount() === 0 ) {


            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)");
            $stmt->execute(array($username, $password));
            if($stmt->rowCount() ===1){
                echo 'Registration complete';
            }else {
                echo 'Sorry, unknown error: please try again later';

            }

            }else {
                echo 'Sorry, the username '.$username.' already exists';
            }



        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, it seems to be working. The echo's just aren't appearing.

Comment: Okay, it seems to be working. The echo's just aren't appearing, the password checking or anything. Doesn't enter anything into the database either (Even if trying a new username). I'll make sure all the database information is correct.

Comment: @JohnathanBrown  Actually, I had made some silly mistakes, just check it now. Because, I tried it in my database, and it works.

Comment: Please don't forget to replace `dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx',`  
with database name, username, and password

Comment: Okay, so              $db_name = 
            $db_user = 
            $db_pass = 

I leave blank, but I change the $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx',. Also, I already have a config.php file with this information in

Comment: Yes, just copy/paste the code, and replace those xxx, xxx, xxx, with your database name, username(for database), and password(for the database user)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why it isn't working. I already have a config.php file though, could this be causing an issue? http://pastebin.com/BQnpeDJZ

Comment: @JohnathanBrown Do not include any file to it. Just use the the code I gave you in a single, file. like `example.php` and only change the three `xxx`'s only.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. for more PHP tutorials, check tizag.com and this link for video tutorials. http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11

Comment: I've had to change the home page though lol. Getting there, just getting it to recognise the user. Should work soon. Thanks. I love thenewboston! I used him for Java :). Login page works as well now! Thanks again dude

Answer (score 1):

Did you omit the part where you execute the query? All I see is that you're assigning the query to a variable but not executing it.

I see that you're using PDO, so you should NOT concatenate the username you're checking for into the query, as it leaves you open to SQL injection. I'm assuming your database object is called "$con" and your table is codecalltut. Do this:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM codecalltut WHERE username=?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($qry);
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['username']));
$exists = ($stmt->rowCount() === 1) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last `;` :

```
$qry = "SELECT username
    FROM codecalltut
    WHERE username = username;";
               REMOVE THIS --^ ^----ADD THIS
```

Comment: Those `;` terminators are generally harmless - especially considering you don't know what API is being called by `storeFormValues()`.  What's missing is the `;` _after the PHP statement_ and proper quoting of `username`

Comment: So I don't actually need the ; for mySQL queries? I shall remember that, thank you. 

EDIT:
Just added the ; after the statement, thanks Michael

Comment: Thanks Michael added the ending `;` to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Followed by what @Nelson said. You should also enclose strings in your query with `'` single quotes like this:

```
$qry = "SELECT username FROM codecalltut   WHERE username = 'username' ";
```

Also, if you are writting inside, any table, row names, which might conflict with the database language itself, make sure to enclose them with backticks (`)

**bytheway**

A simple login script would work out this way. (hope, you are using `PDO` or `mysqli` instead of mysql functions to interact with your database

```
// set isset(), to validate if form is submited and then

    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $pass= $_POST['pass'];
```

Now, the code.

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=***;', 'db-user', 'user-pass');

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username,password from members WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");

$stmt->execute(array($username, $password));
if($stmt->rowCount() === 1){
echo 'welcome'.$username;
}else {
echo $username.' is not found'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I still seem to be getting duplicated users in my database though.

Comment: Thank you, you also forgot a ; after echo $username.' is not found' ? I am still getting duplication's though. After looking at my code though, I don't even think all of these will do anything. Once the user has clicked "Register" it goes straight back to the index.php page. Perhaps I should update the original post with the button code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean, by duplications? do you have a two accounts in your database, which have same username and passwords? Show me your registration code, you can post it in pastbin.com

Comment: http://pastebin.com/npDj75XR. By duplication's I mean duplicate users in my database.

Comment: The code I gave you was for login, but you just included it in the register form, and sent it back to me, this means you have no clue about PHP at all. Now, if I understand you are having problems, because your database, is submitting, same username with same password, and you want to have only a unique name right?

Comment: Sorry I gave you an outdated version, when I read over it I realised it was for the login.php. Sorry about that PHP Fan. And yes, I would like it to only accept unique names basically.

Comment: Ok, Give me 5 minutes, I am creating the code for you. is [this](http://appsmarketing.net/login/register.php) your website btw

Comment: No, I am using WAMP server to test it out. I'll upload everything though if you wish?

Comment: No need. Do you have PDO installed?

Comment: I do indeed, thank you.

Comment: Ok, what is your table name

Comment: My table name is users

Comment: @JohnathanBrown Ok, check it. I have not tested it, and tell me if it has any problem